# ordenar dados numéricos mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Estou tentando ordenar dados numericos com um campo definido como number na collection e a ordenação nao apresenta conforme eu preciso. Exemplo: 1,2,3,10 apos a ordenação o resultado apresentado: 1,10,2,3. Como modificar o resultado?
estou usando o comando:

```
var itgrpdados = (dados.grpdados).sort({sq_itemgrupodados:1});
```

Comment: O campo que possui os números que quer ordenar é o `sq_itemgrupodados`?

Comment: sim, este campo é para ordenar os dados para que o usuario defina qual a sequencia: ele está definido na collection como Number, mas já tentei como String e nao alterou o resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Tentei montar um cenário o mais parecido possível com o seu, e obtive alguns resultados interessantes.

**1.** Criei um *database* chamado `dados`

**2.** Criei uma *collection* chamada `grpdados`

E adicionei `4` documentos na *collection* `grpdados`:

```
{
    "_id":  {
    "$oid": "5b5923b4fb6fc07c4c24156e"
},
    "sq_itemgrupodados": "1"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b592417fb6fc07c4c241593"
    },
    "sq_itemgrupodados": "2"
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b5923fcfb6fc07c4c24158e"
    },
    "sq_itemgrupodados": "3"
},{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b592429fb6fc07c4c241595"
    },
    "sq_itemgrupodados": "10"
}
```

Após isso, fiz uma busca por `sq_itemgrupodados` e ordenei usando o `sort()` de forma ascendente:

```
dados.grpdados.sort({"sq_itemgrupodados":1})
```

#### Resultado:

`{1, 10, 2, 3}` (***Exatamente como o seu, tudo certo até aqui!***)

Então fiz uma pequena alteração nos documentos, **ao invés de passar um valor `string`, alterei para o valor `inteiro`**, exemplo:

```
 {
        "_id":  {
        "$oid": "5b5923b4fb6fc07c4c24156e"
    },
        "sq_itemgrupodados": 1
 }
```

Fazendo isso para os `4` documentos, e fazendo novamente a busca e ordenando com o `sort()`:

#### Resultado:

`{1,2,3,10}` (***ordenado em ordem ascendente, como queríamos!***)

#### Conclusão

Acredito que tenha sido apenas um equívoco com relação ao tipo dos dados que está tentando ordenar, para `string` ele vai ordenar pelo valor da tabela [ascii](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), logo `10 < 2`  e `10 < 3`.

**EDIT:** Criei uma *sandbox* para testes no *mongolab*, então se isso não resolver podemos tentar outras alternativas :)

Comment: grato pela ajuda. Só para alinhar estou usando nodejs, javascript. o item dados foi o resultado de um find: (não sei se ficará longa) mas vou tentar.

Comment: eu tentei enviar um texto mas ficou longo, de qualquer forma vou tentar realizar conforme sugerido.

Comment: veja a definição da colection:
module.exports = function() {
 var itensgrpdadosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ds_itemgrupodados : {type: String, trim: true},
  sq_itemgrupodados : {type: Number, trim: true,default:0},
 });
 var grupodadosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  cd_grupodados : {type: String, trim: true, index: true},
  grpdados  : [itensgrpdadosSchema]
 });
 return mongoose.model('Grupodados', grupodadosSchema);
}

Comment: a definição do item sq_itemgrupodados é Number, e estou lendo no js com o comando:Grupodadositens.findById(req.params.id,function(err,dados){... var itgrpdados = (dados.grpdados).sort({sq_itemgrupodados:1}); ..}); ode o nome da collection é Grupodadositens. estou tentando ordenar o item sq_itemgrupodados que está dentro de um sub com o nome de grpdados. (não sei se a formatação dará um boa compreensão).

Comment: @GerciLisboa, seria interessante se adicionasse essas informações no corpo da pergunta. Vou fazer alguns testes com o cenário que descreveu e lhe dou um retorno :)

Comment: ok, sou novo neste forum, vou proceder desta forma daqui por diante.

Comment: @GerciLisboa algum resultado?

Comment: editei a pergunta novamente e inclui mais detalhes, nao sei se desta forma ficará mais compreensivel. Grato.

Answer (score -1):

@Tuxpilgrim eu realizei um teste, mas não deu certo. Talvez porque eu estou realizando o sort apos realizar o comando Find, pois o que eu desejo order é um sub formulario. 
onde o item dados é a collection, grpdados subformulario de dados e sq_itemgrupodados é onde estao os dados para ordenar. eu li o formulario usando o comando:

```
Grupodadositens.findById(req.params.id,function(err,dados){
-...
var itgrpdados = (dados.grpdados).sort({sq_itemgrupodados:1});
});
```

na definição da collection o item sq_itemgrupodados é Number.
segue a definição da collection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function() {
    var itensgrpdadosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        ds_itemgrupodados   : {type: String, trim: true},
        sq_itemgrupodados   : {type: Number, trim: true,default:0},
        id_exb_grp_dados    : {type: String, trim: true}
    });
    var grupodadosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        cd_grupodados   : {type: String, trim: true, index: true},
        ds_grupodados   : {type: String, required: true,trim: true},
        cd_entidade     : {type: String, trim: true},
        ds_objgrpdados  : {type: String, trim: true},
        ds_titulogrupo  : {type: String, required: true,trim: true},
        grpdados        : [itensgrpdadosSchema],
        id_ativo        : {type: String, trim: true},
        data_cad        : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    });
    return mongoose.model('Grupodados', grupodadosSchema);
}
```

Pergunta: Teria como ordenar diretamente na leitura inicial,sem ler primeiramente o formulario e depois ordernar conforme fiz acima?